# Java PKIX path building failed as non Admin

Tags: java, maven

I updated the connection to my local repository from HTTP to HTTPS and I added the certificate to cacerts. Since then I have an issue, that I can't run `mvn clean install` as a normal user. When I run VS Code as an Administrator I don't get that error. I want to build my project as a normal user too.

I guess it's something wrong with some rights, but I don't know what exactly. I installed both Java and Maven, under C:/Programm Files.

I gave my non-admin account full access to the Java and Maven folder.

The difference to similar questions is, that the build only runs as an admin, but not as a normal user. I already followed the steps in similar questions, but they don't solved my problem yet.

Comment: Possibly the certificate is in a copy of cacerts in the virtual store of your admin profile, instead of the "real" cacerts in the Java directory, or your admin uses a different install of Java than your normal user.